# Create distance matrix from 2D-equidistant matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have an equidistant two-dimensional grid with N points, so n x n size. I want to create a NxN distance matrix D where element D_ij is the distance between point i and point j.

E.g matrix [[a b],[c d]] should have distance matrix
[[0 1 1 1.414],[1 0 1.1.414 1], [1 1.414 0 1],[1.414 1 1 0]].

I have done this in a very brute force way, shown below

```
N=2**2
n=int(np.sqrt(N))

row = np.arange(0,n)
grid = np.tile(row,n)

#East matrix. For each point, the matrix yields the distance in the x direction(east) to the other points. The first row covers each point in the first row in the grid, and so on.

D_E = np.zeros((N,N))
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        
        D_E[i,j] = grid[j]-grid[i]
#Same logic as above, but this time in the y_direction
D_S = np.zeros((N,N))

row2 = np.arange(0,n)
grid2 = np.repeat(row2,n)
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        D_S[i,j] = grid2[j]-grid2[i]

D = np.sqrt(D_E**2 + D_S**2)
```

Is there any better way to do this, perhaps more pythonic that I have not thought about?

PS.

I can add that the main goal in the end is to create a covariance matrix for the grid, using the distance matrix D to create the N x N covariance matrix, since each element in the covariance matrix is decided by the covariance function which inputs the euclidian distance between points in the grid.

Comment: Why do you need multiple copies of the distance matrix? `[[0 1 1 1.414],[1 0 1.1.414 1], [1 1.414 0 1],[1.414 1 1 0]]` They are all the same, just shifted over? You can just use the first one?

Comment: They are similar for this example, but when n is larger the rows start having different values. E.g with 9 elements in the matrix, the distance between the top left element and the bottom right is 2sqrt(2), which only shows up twice in the entire distance matrix.

Comment: What does this `[[a b],[c d]]` matrix represent? Distance between a to b and c to d? Can you give an example that correlates with the `D` matrix you have shown?

Comment: Yes, just an equidistant grid. So the values themselves are not important, only the actual physical distance between the points matter.